# Failing to get a proper json from a freemaker list

Tags: json, freemarker

I'm trying to get a working JSON output (an array with x amount of objects) from a freemaker ftl file.  If there is only 1 object in th array of "loggedInUsers" then the code below works.  If there are more than 1, then the JSON breaks.  I know a comma should separate the separate between each, but the problem comes when I add one after the closing brace. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
    <#list loggedInUsers as user>
        {
            "user": "${user}"
        }
    </#list>
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to add a comma except after the last item. In that case use the `#sep` directive, like `}<#sep>,</#sep>`. (See also: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give that a try.  I found this last night through trial and error which *I think* is giving me what I want: `<#if (user_has_next) > 
    ,
  </#if>`

Comment: `#sep` is the short form of `<#if user?has_next>,</#if>`.